# How to get searched strings (not lines) in a file using PowerShell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a file that contains multiples strings between parentheses that represents country's names.

```
This (USA) is a bad text (France)
with countries (Luxembourg) between () (Germany)
Whith multiple (Luxembourg) countries (USA) per line
and some lines without countries
To search (France) and find (Belgique) duplicate
countries (USA)
```

I want to extract all countries and display each country found on a new line.

What I'm expecting is following

```
USA
France
Luxembourg
Germany
Luxembourg
USA
France
Belgique
USA
```

Using a special tool named `BS2EDT` editor on `BS2000` Mainframe, the solution can be

```
list-string /(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\))/,from=lettre.pays.txt
```

Using `PowerShell`, what is the shorter solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following tricky solutions is working on my PC

```
$regex = '(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\))'
(Select-String .\lettre.pays.txt -Pattern $regex -AllMatches).Matches `
        | Select-String -Pattern '.*' `
```

`Get-Content` command read input file.

First `Select-String` command find ALL strings using same Regex given in question.

`.Matches` and second `Select-String` command display strings found.

It is also possible to sort all countries found in adding `SORT-OBJECT` command !

```
$regex = '(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\))'
(Select-String .\lettre.pays.txt -Pattern $regex -AllMatches).Matches `
        | Select-String -Pattern '.*' `
            | Sort-Object
```

that display following result ...

```
Belgique
France
France
Germany
Luxembourg
Luxembourg
USA
USA
USA
```

Comment: the solution with `For-Each-Object` is more powerful because it allows using other properties than 'Value'.

Answer (score 0):

Using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) you can accomplish it using [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.3), definitely not *shorter* than what you already have:

```
Select-String .\lettre.pays.txt -Pattern '(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\))' -AllMatches |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

As for your regex, I believe `(?=\))` is not needed and could be removed from the pattern.